# Is it possible to retrieve the photo tags from a fanpage?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The situation is the following:
I have created a fanpage.
I have tagged the fanpage in my photos.
I have created an app.

Here's what I would like to achieve:
Let the app retrieve the photos in which the fanpage has been tagged.

I have managed to retrieve tags in which an individual FB-user has been tagged, after getting
an access-token with offline_access from this user. This does not seem to work for a fanpage though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a page access token to do your query against a page.